# If a monero transaction has two inputs and one output, is it possible to partially sign the transaction of just one input?

Tags: viewkey, privatekey

If a monero transaction has two inputs and one output, is it possible to partially sign the transaction of just one input?

If so, is it currently possible to export it from the core wallet or any other wallet?
If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible yet, but is being considered.